# How to get textbox value from other class?

Tags: java, textfield

I have a problem regarding the JTextField, I always get a NullPointerException whenever i want to get the textfield value from my class Student and pass it to my other class which is class myAction what i want to happen is that after i clicked the button or Jbutton all the data in the textfield will be save to the array, and i already have an actionlistener to my button and create a class myAction.

Here are my code:
Student class(Main class)

/*

```
package Student;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class Student{
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public String[] name = {"Lara", "Jerome", "Ferdie", "Jeffrey", "Eduard", "King"};
    public int[] grade = new int[6];
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6;
    JPanel panel;
    public JTextField text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6;
    JButton button;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Student myStudent = new Student();
        myStudent.Layout();
        //myStudent.
    }

    public void GetValue()
    {
        grade[0] = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
        grade[1] = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText());
        grade[2] = Integer.parseInt(text3.getText());
        grade[3] = Integer.parseInt(text4.getText());
        grade[4] = Integer.parseInt(text5.getText());
        grade[5] = Integer.parseInt(text6.getText());

        for(int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(grade[i]);
        }
    }

    public void Layout()
    {
        //Design Layout
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame = new JFrame("Student Grades");
        button = new JButton("Get Grade");
        button.setBounds(50, 260, 200, 30);
        label1 = new JLabel("Your Grade: " + name[0]);
        label1.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 30);
        text1 = new JTextField(5);
        text1.setBounds(140, 15, 150, 20);
        label2 = new JLabel("Your Grade: " + name[1]);
        label2.setBounds(10, 50, 150, 30);
        text2 = new JTextField(5);
        text2.setBounds(140, 55, 150, 20);
        label3 = new JLabel("Your Grade: " + name[2]);
        label3.setBounds(10, 90, 150, 30);
        text3 = new JTextField(5);
        text3.setBounds(140, 95, 150, 20);
        label4 = new JLabel("Your Grade: " + name[3]);
        label4.setBounds(10, 130, 150, 30);
        text4 = new JTextField(5);
        text4.setBounds(140, 135, 150, 20);
        label5 = new JLabel("Your Grade: " + name[4]);
        label5.setBounds(10, 170, 150, 30);
        text5 = new JTextField(5);
        text5.setBounds(140, 175, 150, 20);
        label6 = new JLabel("Your Grade: " + name[5]);
        label6.setBounds(10,210, 150, 30);
        text6 = new JTextField(5);
        text6.setBounds(140, 215, 150, 20);
        frame.setSize(350, 350);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(text1);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(text2);
        panel.add(label3);
        panel.add(text3);
        panel.add(label4);
        panel.add(text4);
        panel.add(label5);
        panel.add(text5);
        panel.add(label6);
        panel.add(text6);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyEvent myAction = new MyEvent();
        button.addActionListener(myAction);
    }

}

and my class myAction(or actionlistener) class

class MyEvent implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
      if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Get Grade"))
      {
          Student EventStudent = new Student();
          EventStudent.GetValue();

      }
    }   
}
```

*/
here are all my code hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is you created a Student object in main.So your text fields are associated with that object.Now in your event listener you are creating another object of the student that doesn't belong with any of the component you need.you have to retrieve data from the object in the main method.
Do like below.Hopefully it will help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class Student{
    static Student myStudent ;
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public String[] name = {"Lara", "Jerome", "Ferdie", "Jeffrey", "Eduard", "King"};
    public int[] grade = new int[6];
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6;
    JPanel panel;
    public JTextField text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6;
    JButton button;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         myStudent = new Student();
         myStudent.Layout();
        //myStudent.
    }

    public void GetValue()
    {
        grade[0] = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
        grade[1] = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText());
        grade[2] = Integer.parseInt(text3.getText());
        grade[3] = Integer.parseInt(text4.getText());
        grade[4] = Integer.parseInt(text5.getText());
        grade[5] = Integer.parseInt(text6.getText());

        for(int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(grade[i]);
        }
    }

    public void Layout()
    {
        //Design Layout
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame = new JFrame("Student Grades");
        button = new JButton("Get Grade");
        button.setBounds(50, 260, 200, 30);
        label1 = new JLabel("Your Grade: " + name[0]);
        label1.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 30);
        text1 = new JTextField(5);
        text1.setBounds(140, 15, 150, 20);
        label2 = new JLabel("Your Grade: " + name[1]);
        label2.setBounds(10, 50, 150, 30);
        text2 = new JTextField(5);
        text2.setBounds(140, 55, 150, 20);
        label3 = new JLabel("Your Grade: " + name[2]);
        label3.setBounds(10, 90, 150, 30);
        text3 = new JTextField(5);
        text3.setBounds(140, 95, 150, 20);
        label4 = new JLabel("Your Grade: " + name[3]);
        label4.setBounds(10, 130, 150, 30);
        text4 = new JTextField(5);
        text4.setBounds(140, 135, 150, 20);
        label5 = new JLabel("Your Grade: " + name[4]);
        label5.setBounds(10, 170, 150, 30);
        text5 = new JTextField(5);
        text5.setBounds(140, 175, 150, 20);
        label6 = new JLabel("Your Grade: " + name[5]);
        label6.setBounds(10,210, 150, 30);
        text6 = new JTextField(5);
        text6.setBounds(140, 215, 150, 20);
        frame.setSize(350, 350);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(text1);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(text2);
        panel.add(label3);
        panel.add(text3);
        panel.add(label4);
        panel.add(text4);
        panel.add(label5);
        panel.add(text5);
        panel.add(label6);
        panel.add(text6);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyEvent myAction = new MyEvent(myStudent);
        button.addActionListener(myAction);
    }

}
class MyEvent implements ActionListener
{
    Student myStudent;
    public MyEvent(Student myStudent) {
        this.myStudent=myStudent;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
      if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Get Grade"))
      {

         myStudent.GetValue();

      }
    }   
}
```